# Windows Phone 8.1 - This app is not available for your device although I can manually deploy it into the device

Tags: windows-phone-8.1, windows-phone, windows-store-apps

I have recently finished working on an App for Windows Phone 8.1 and 10 - I have successfully been able to deploy it on both type of phone by using Windows Phone Application Deployment 8.1 tool.

I am now trying to load the app into the store and create a flight package so my develop phone should be able to see, download and install the app from the Microsoft Store on the device.

I am having 2 'problems' right now:
+ the App is not showing on the Store
+ using the app URL from the store, I am able to find the app but it is only available for downloading on the Windows 10 phone and it comes back unavailable on the Windows Phone 8.1

Here is some screenshots which should give an idea of my set ups:

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Apart from the above, I would like to mention that I have added my Microsoft account to the devices so ideally I should be able to see the App!

Let me know guys if it makes sense and if you need further details to help me

Thanks

Comment: Package flights require `Windows.Mobile build 10586.63` so you should get non-flighted package on your Windows Phone 8.1 device. Can you make sure your non-flighted submission gets published successfully in Windows 8.1 Store?  You could try it on another WP 8.1 device or on simulator to find it by direct url. For the problem of your app not being shown on Store, you could create a [support ticket](http://aka.ms/storesupport) so that Dev Center support can help to review your specific package. Usually, it takes 24 hours after submission passes certification but sometimes it takes longer.

Comment: I have not managed to publish the App on the Windows 8.1 store and I have tried the App in other 8.1 devices - it works when I deploy it directly to the device.

Comment: I have contacted support and the problems is on the Pricing and Availability section under 'Visibility'.
As mentioned on the documentation, https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/publish/set-app-pricing-and-availability I should have an options saying:
"Individuals on Windows Phone 8.x only: Only people you specify below can download ...." - this option is not showing and support is going to sort that out hopefully

Thanks

Comment: if your app is specifically for mobiles phone can you upload arm package instead of any cpu ?